# Java Empty String equals NULL

Tags: java, string, hibernate, null, struts

I have the following problem:

We are writing a web application using **Hibernate** and **Struts**. Upon submit, I want to check, if a DB update has be executed or not. So I pull the Object out of the DB and compare it to the data in the form (let's assume, I have a `Person` object with some attributes like `Name`, `Address`, etc.).

Now if the field `Address` on the web form is empty the form property would give me an `""` (*Empty String*). If I take the `Address` property which I got from the DB object and compare it to the form property, the comparison would return `FALSE` because I compare an `""` (*Empty String*) with `NULL` which obviousley is not the same.

I tried the following methods:

```
if (StringUtils.equals(formObj.getAddress(), dbObj.getAddress())) {
        dbObj.getAddress(formObj.getAddress());
        dbObj.update();
}
if (ObjectUtils.equals(formObj.getAddress(), dbObj.getAddress())) {
        dbObj.getAddress(formObj.getAddress());
        dbObj.update();
}
```

My question is: Is there a method that could take these to String Values and compares them, whereby `"" == NULL` would return `TRUE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave my solution here:

I added a method in our own StringUtils class (we call it `StringTools` to avoid conflicts with Apache's `StringUtils`) for this purpose:

```
public static boolean notEqualHibernateProperty(String s1, String s2) {
     return !ObjectUtils.equals(StringUtils.defaultString(s1), StringUtils.defaultString(s2));
}
```

`StringUtils.defaultString(s)` returns an empty String, if the parameters value is `NULL`. 
Then I simply changed the update condition to:

```
if (StringTools.notEqualHibernateProperty(formObj.getAddress(), dbObj.getAddress())) {
     dbObj.getAddress(formObj.getAddress());
     dbObj.update();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, because they are not the same. `""` is *very different* from `null`.

Now if you want this behavior write a custom method:

```
static boolean checkIfEmptyOrNull(String s1, String s2) {
     //check for empty and null
     return myBooleanValue;
}
```

Mark this as *static* because this should be a helper (and should probably go in a helper class as well)

Comment: @piet.t - They had already created DBs *before* they bought *Sun* :P

Comment: That's what we thought too. Oracle is the first DB I know, that handles "" as NULL... I'd like to know why :P

Comment: @rGunti - Maybe because at a *low level* `""` and `null` makes no difference and they both represnt "nothing"

Comment: @piet.t They new it as of 8.0, but not sure if this comply to SQL standards.

Answer (score 1):

As oracle stores all empty strings as `null`, we have been mapping the respective columns with a custom data-type that maps all `null`-values in the database to empty strings. So all `String`s read from the database will be empty instead of null.

To create this type you implement a class extending `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;`:

```
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;
public class OracleStringType implements UserType {...}
```

Most required method-implementations are quite straightforward, as you just return the parameter passed in. The most interesting are these:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object arg0, Object arg1) throws HibernateException {
    if(arg0 == null) arg0 = "";
    if(arg1 == null) arg1 = "";
    return arg0.equals(arg1);
}
@Override
public int hashCode(Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    if(arg0==null) arg0="";
    return arg0.hashCode();
}
@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    String result = resultSet.getString(names[0]);
    if(resultSet.wasNull()) return "";
    return result;
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if(value == null) {
        statement.setNull(index, Hibernate.STRING.sqlType());
    } else {
        String valueString = (String)value;
        statement.setString(index, valueString);
    }
}
```

Comment: We thought of this ourself too but since we had to change a lot of our Hibernate classes for this, we discarded this approch. Another problem we thought of, if we'd use another DB (other than Oracle), this behavour would become unhandy.

Answer (score 0):

use this additional condition:

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(formObj.getAddress()) && StringUtils.isEmpty( dbObj.getAddress()))
```